# Sylius event listener on order update

Tags: symfony, sylius

I am looking to set up an event listener in my bundle to listen for when an order has been set to completed or refunded.

I successfully created an event listener using the code from this link:

https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius-Docs/blob/master/bundles/general/events.rst

Here is my listener code

```
namespace myBundle\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\GenericEvent;

class SolrListener 
{    

    public function onOrderUpdate(GenericEvent $event)
    {
        echo "I have hooked into it !!!";
        exit();
    }
}
```

And here is my service entry:

```
    myBundle.listener.solr:
    class: myBundle\EventListener\SolrListener
    tags:
       -  { name: kernel.event_listener, event: sylius.orders.post_update, method: onOrderUpdate }
```

My main question is the event.  I tried sylius.orders.post_update and sylius.order.post_update and both didnt pick up.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated and many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can also attach the listeners to state-machine of order state. Every time the transition is made, your listener would be called.

https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/blob/master/src/Sylius/Bundle/OrderBundle/Resources/config/app/state_machine.yml

Comment: That actually might be a better idea.  Would you happen to have some sample code you could post?

I would love to try that out.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  When updating an order, I shouldnt be checking:

sylius.order.post_update

but actually :

sylius.payment.post_update

It is the payment I am updating.

Hope that helps someone out there